# How can I make a list ignored in C# using slite-net?

Tags: c#, sqlite-net

I am trying to implement the observer design pattern and for one table I need a list of observers. However, I don't want this to be added to the table. I tried using [Ignore] but I get this error:

```
attribute 'ignore' is not valid on this declaration type. it is only valid on 'property, indexer' declarations. (cs0592) (core)
```

This is my class (the table is activity) :

```
[PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
        public int IDA { get; set; }
        public String name { get; set; }
        [Ignore] // this generates an error
        public List<IObserver> observers;
```

Comment: Make `observers` a property, rather than a field (i.e., add `{ get; set; }` to the end

Comment: This saved me hours of searching, didn't know I can not apply this to field only. Thank you!

Comment: What if I want a list like public List<IObserver> observers = new List<IObserver>() so it will be instantiated only once/ class, how could I do this and this list still being ignored?

Comment: You can say `public List<IObserver> observers {get; set;} = new List<IObserver>();`  But, that will result in a an `observers` property being instantiated once per instance of the class, not once per class.  If you want something once per class, you need to make it `static`.  If you make it static, I strongly suspect it will be ignored without any annotation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is in the error message, this part: `it is only valid on 'property, indexer' declarations`

Make observers a property, rather than a field (i.e., add `{ get; set; }` to the end of the declaration